# Divi Builder (plugin) not working on WordPress 5.0.2

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site built on Divi Buider already. But, after updating my WordPress version to 5.0.2 Divi Builder plugin stopped working on frontend and also on dashboard (on Edit Page). My Divi Builder plugin version is also updated (version 2.19.4).

I think it may happen because of conflicting with Guterberg. I tried to disable Gutenberg by installing plugins like "Disable Gutenberg" or "Classic Editor". Those show Divi Editor on Dashboard (edit page) again, but, Divi Buider on frontend it's still loading forever...

Comment: Could be a lot of reasons. I'd start with your error logs, if that isn't helpful. Do a fresh install and slowly add in one plugin at a time until it breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line in function.php, it will help you to disable Gutenberg, after that your divi builder will work perfectly.

add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_false');

Answer (score 0):

if adding below code mentioned by @oovii.alee didnt work

**add_filter('use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_false');**

try adding this plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/

and then change settings in settings->writting